# How can I use AOP functionality with Spring AOP not with aspectj?

Tags: spring, spring-aop

```
<aop:config>
    <aop:aspect id="myAspect" ref="aBean">
    <aop:pointcut id="businessService"
      expression="execution(* com.xyz.myapp.service.*.*(..))"/>
    <aop:advice............>

</aop:aspect>
```

When I use the configuration above, it will use aspectj. How can I use Spring AOP only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will use spring-aop with you code example, not aspectj

Comment: **public Object doBesicProfiling(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp)  {
  System.out.println("enter method");
  Object result = pjp.proceed();
  System.out.println("exit method");
  return result;
 }** this is method in my aspect and class ProceedingJoinPoint  is from aspectjrt.jar

Comment: please, read spring-aop documentation http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html You cannot use full aspectj syntax and all his features with your configuration